# zero tasks are running in Celery with supervisor

Tags: django, celery

I am using Celery with Django, and it works perfectly fine when I use the `celery` command and run the `worker` and `beat` individually, but when I use supervisor to run Celery as a daemon, no tasks start running.

```
supervisorctl status all
[sudo] password for ahmed: 
beat                             RUNNING   pid 22064, uptime 1:29:20
worker                           RUNNING   pid 22063, uptime 1:29:20
```

`celery.conf` file in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/celery.conf`

```
; ==========================================
;  celery worker config
; ==========================================

[program: worker]
command=/home/ahmed/.local/bin/celery -A decimal_trade worker -l info
directory=/home/ahmed/PycharmProjects/decimal-trade
user=ahmed
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/ahmed/PycharmProjects/decimal-trade/celery/log/worker.log
stderr_logfile=/home/ahmed/PycharmProjects/decimal-trade/celery/log/worker.err.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600
killasgroup=true
priority=998
; priority 998 executes first and then 999

; ========================================
; celery beat config
; ========================================

[program: beat]
command=/home/ahmed/.local/bin/celery -A decimal_trade beat -l info
directory=/home/ahmed/PycharmProjects/decimal-trade
user=ahmed
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/ahmed/PycharmProjects/decimal-trade/celery/log/beat.log
stderr_logfile=/home/ahmed/PycharmProjects/decimal-trade/celery/log/beat.err.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600
killasgroup=true
priority=999
```

The `worker` log

```
 
 -------------- celery@ahmed-Lenovo-V14-G1-IML v5.3.6 (emerald-rush)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-6.2.0-39-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35 2024-03-14 18:19:37
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         decimal_trade:0x7fa64756c3d0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/0
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[tasks]
  . symbols.tasks.task_one
  . symbols.tasks.task_two
```

the `beat` log

```
celery beat v5.3.6 (emerald-rush) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2024-03-14 18:29:37
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://localhost:6379/0
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
```